# Sync scrolling of two frames (browser-agnostic, please!)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, scroll, frames

I have a web page made of three frames, something like this:

```
+----------------+
|       0        |
+-------+--------+
|       |        |
|   1   |    2   |
|       |        |
+-------+--------+
```

Frames `1` and `2` are for comparing some similar data.  I'd like to sync the vertical scrollbars on these frames (setting the scroll bar value on both sides to be the same).

My current approach is to have the following code in frame `0`:

```
<script>
   function scroll_sync() {
      var f1 = window.parent.frames[1];
      var f2 = window.parent.frames[2];

      f1.onscroll = function () { f2.scroll(f2.scrollX, f1.scrollY); }
      f2.onscroll = function () { f1.scroll(f1.scrollX, f2.scrollY); }
   }

  dojo.addOnLoad(scroll_sync);
</script>
```

This works fine in Firefox 3.x and Chrome 5.x.  Not in Internet Explorer 8, though.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In IE I think you need to use `scrollTo` like: `f2.scrollTo(0,f1_scroll_position);`

Comment: I think the problem is with `scrollX` property, not the `scroll` method, which does work in IE